# I have installed Imagick but am seeing "Error: Class 'Imagick' not found". What am I missing?

Tags: php, imagick

I am on RHEL 7.

I have installed imagick with...

```
yum install php-imagick
```

I added to my php.ini...

```
extension=imagick
```

I have confirmed that I am using the correct php.ini in my file system. It is the "Loaded Configuration File" when I print phpinfo() to a file.

I restarted apache.

In my PHP application, I am getting...

```
Error: Class 'Imagick' not found
```

At least at the command line, Imagick is installed...

```
[root@localhost rh-php72]# convert --version
Version: ImageMagick 6.7.8-9 2019-04-15 Q16 http://www.imagemagick.org
Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2012 ImageMagick Studio LLC
Features: OpenMP
```

But the class is not found in my PHP app.

Comment: Your version of Imagemagick is very old.  I have no idea what RHEL 7 is but I think you need to have the correct versions of Imagemagick and Imagick. Note Linux tends to patch a default version of Imagemagick and not install an uptodate one. It looks like in your case the base version is a 2012 version.

Comment: Thanks.  RHEL is Red Hat Enterprise Linux.  I should write it out.  I have since moved the project to Ubuntu, and Imagick now works, even though my version is quite old, like you say.